# Performance issues with Unity-AnimatorOverrideController

Tags: unity-game-engine

Using the AnimatorOverrideController to dynamically modify the animationclip in a state will recalculate all states and related curve data in the controller, resulting in performance consumption.

But why is AnimatorController designed like this, Can't I just recalculate the data for this part of the state I modified?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason why AnimatorOverrideController is designed to recalculate all states and related curve data in the controller when dynamically modifying an animation clip in a state is because the animation system in Unity is based on a state machine. Each state in the state machine has a set of animations and associated curves that define how the object or character should behave in that state. When an animation clip is modified in a state, it affects the entire state, not just the part of the state that was modified.

Recalculating all states and related curve data ensures that the entire state machine is consistent and behaves correctly. If only the modified part of the state was recalculated, it could result in unexpected behavior or errors in the animation.

While recalculating all states and related curve data can consume a lot of performance, there are ways to optimize the animation system in Unity. For example, you can reduce the number of curves in the animation clips or optimize the use of the AnimatorOverrideController by only modifying the animation clip when necessary. Additionally, you can also use techniques such as object pooling and caching to reduce the impact on performance.